# Change texture with random

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I have some textures

```
var texturesOfEnemies = [SKTexture(imageNamed: "EnemyTexture1"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "EnemyTexture2"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "EnemyTexture3"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "EnemyTexture4"),
                         SKTexture(imageNamed: "EnemyTexture5")]
```

I'm using `arc4random` to select a random texture

```
var randomTextureOfEnemies = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(texturesOfEnemies.count)))
```

and assign the selected texture to a node by

```
enemy.texture = texturesOfEnemies[randomTextureOfEnemies]
```

I have some actions for my node. When the actions are done, I want to change the texture of my node.

```
enemy.run(someAction, completion:{enemy.texture = texturesOfEnemies[randomTextureOfEnemies]})
```

This actions repeat and are working well, but the textures are only changing once. How can I change the texture every time the action completes?

Comment: You have to compute a new random number. `randomTextureOfEnemies` is never changed after you assign it the first time.

Comment: I'm a beginner in programming(

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Place the `var randomTextureOfEnemies = Int(arc4...` inside of the completion block. And change `var` to `let` since it doesn't change after it's assigned.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer. But I'm trying do this before and it's not working( Texture has changed just only one time

Comment: You have it set up to change the texture only after the action finishes. If you want to change the texture each time the action repeats, you'll need to create a sequence of actions.