# why is my random array not drawing a random texture on each render? what do I have to change?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Before I start I want to state that I am learning, I am completely new. Here i have added as much detail as possible.

So, I have an array of textures of different colors, and set a Random to randomize the textures, Like this:

```
Texture[] bubbles;

Random random = new Random(); 
int lowRange = 0;
int highRange = 3;
int result = random.nextInt(highRange -lowRange) + 1; //my random

ArrayList<Integer> BubbleXs = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> BubbleYs = new ArrayList<>();

@Override 
public void create () {
bubbles = new Texture[4];
bubbles[0] = new Texture("blue.png");
bubbles[1] = new Texture("red.png");
bubbles[2] = new Texture("green.png");
bubbles[3] = new Texture("yellow.png");
}
```

Then I proceed to draw the texture at a random color falling from the top of the screen using a for loop, like this:

```
@Override

public void render () {

    if (BubbleCount < 120) {
        BubbleCount++;
    } else {
        BubbleCount = 0;
        makeBubble();
    }

public void makeBubble () {

    float width = random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    BubbleXs.add((int)width);
    BubbleYs.add(Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
}

for (int i=0; i < BubbleYs.size(); i++) {

    batch.draw(bubbles[result],  BubbleXs.get(i), BubbleYs.get(i)); 
    BubbleYs.set(i, BubbleYs.get(i) -4);
}
```

and it draws the textures at a a random perfectly, but only once, when its created, I want them to be a new random each time its looped, so its a different one every time one falls. why is it not doing that? what am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I checked out this post: [Change texture with random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306264/change-texture-with-random)
but its not really helping any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they're all the same is that you assign a value to `result` only once, when it is initialized, and you never change it. If you want it to change, you need to use your Random to assign another value.

Your formula `random.nextInt(highRange -lowRange) + 1` isn't right if you're wanting a random number between `lowRange` and `highRange` inclusive. That's giving you a number between `lowRange + 1` and `highRange + 1`. The correct formula would be `random.nextInt(highRange - lowRange) + lowRange`.

The way to solve this would be create an additional variable for each bubble that stores the random int. You are already keeping a list for each of the two variables you're already storing (x and y). You could theoretically add a third, but it's to the point where you really just need to create a class for each bubble, so you can expand it easily if you add more features.

```
class Bubble {
    int x;
    int y;
    int textureIndex;
}
```

Then replace your two array lists with:

```
ArrayList<Bubble> bubbles = new ArrayList<>();
```

And your `makeBubble` method should look like this:

```
void makeBubble(){
    Bubble bubble = new Bubble();
    bubble.x = (int)(random.nextFloat() * Gdx.graphics.getWidth());
    bubble.y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    bubble.textureIndex = random.nextInt(3);
}
```

And your for loop for drawing them would look like this. I changed your textures array name here to `bubbleTextures` so `bubbles` can be used for the list of Bubble objects.

```
for (Bubble bubble : bubbles) {
    batch.draw(bubbleTextures[bubble.textureIndex],  bubble.x, bubble.y); 
    bubble.y -= 4;
}
```

There are numerous other issues I'm seeing with your code, but I think it would be overwhelming to explain them all. This at least gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time :)